# jpgraph and x axis

Tags: php, jpgraph

i try to solve a problem in jpGraph.As you see above this my graph and x axis consists of times.But there are also numbers like 20 30 40 50 60. Can i hide them ? Is there a way to do that?

This is my code

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
require_once ('jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph_line.php');

ini_set("display_errors","off");
$getJson = file_get_contents("http://borsa.doviz.com/hisse_grafik_ajax/XU100/hisse/minute/json",false);

$j = json_decode($getJson);
$i = 0;
$datay1 = array();
$datay2 = array();
$max = 0;
foreach($j as $result)
{
    $datay1[]=$result->KAPANIS;
    $arr = explode(" ",$result->TARIH);
    $arr2 = explode(":",$arr[1]);
    $datay2[]=$arr2[0] . ":" . $arr2[1];
    if($arr[0] > $max)
        $max = $arr[0];
}


// Setup the graph
$graph = new Graph(450,300);
$graph->SetScale('intlin',0,0,0,70);


$theme_class= new UniversalTheme;
$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);




$graph->SetBox(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);


// For background to be gradient, setfill is needed first.
$graph->ygrid->SetFill(true,'#FFFFFF@0.5','#FFFFFF@0.5');
$graph->SetBackgroundGradient('#F0F8FF', '#FFFFFF', GRAD_HOR, BGRAD_PLOT);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($datay2); $i++)
{
    if($datay2[$i] == ":")
        $datay2[$i] = "";
}





$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($datay2);
$graph->xaxis->HideLastTickLabel();

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($datay2); $i++)
{
    if($datay2[$i] == ":")
        $datay2[$i] = "";
}





// Create the line
$p1 = new LinePlot($datay1);
$graph->Add($p1);



$p1->SetFillGradient('#00FF7F','#FFFFFF');
$p1->SetColor('#aadddd');



// Output line
$graph->Stroke();

?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I really spend my hours to solve it. 
I first find the class named jpgraph.

find  this place

```
 // ticks_label has an entry for each data point and is the array
                // that holds the labels set by the user. If the user hasn't
                // specified any values we use whats in the automatically asigned
                // labels in the maj_ticks_label
                if (isset($this->ticks_label[$i * $m])) {
                    $label = $this->ticks_label[$i * $m];
                } else {
                    if ($aAbsLabel) {
                        $label = abs($this->scale->ticks->maj_ticks_label[$i]);
                    } else {
                        $label = $this->scale->ticks->maj_ticks_label[$i];
```

and add

```
if($label == 60)
                              $label = "";
                        elseif ($label == 50)
                             $label = "";
                         elseif ($label == 40)
                             $label = "";
                          elseif ($label == 30)
                             $label = "";
                           elseif ($label == 20)
                             $label = "";
                            elseif ($label == 10)
                             $label = "";
```